# Can a (BOOT/BIOS) Virus affect a Linux LiveCD session?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, ubuntu-12.04, virus, livecd

### Question:

> Is it possible for a virus that infected a PC with Windows OS to show
>   similar erroneous behaviour during a LiveCD session with Ubuntu?
>
> **N.B.** To clarify my question: Can the liveCD *experience* be ruined by a BIOS virus (Not the CD itself, I know it is readonly...)

### Background

Speaking from a recent experience:
A friend has an old XP PC that has suddenly started opening Outlook Express 6 everytime he logs in. **Any non-IE browser** (Chrome/Mozilla) crashes, and Kaspersky Antivirus also crashes within 2 minutes of starting a scan. I advised him not to use IE8 for browsing.

When I tried booting into it with Ubuntu LiveCD, it kept opening Thunderbird (Default Email client in Ubuntu), and would not let me configure DSL (it cleared all settings after 15-20 seconds of typing in username/password etc). This happened to me for the 1st time with Linux live CDs, usually they're pretty solid.

I am suspecting there is some BIOS virus which may be causing this, but is this a possibility with a Linux LiveCD too?

**[Edit]**
The CPU was sent to a mechanic who found many virii and was unable to clean it without formatting the drive (after taking data backup). Still not sure if a bios virus was there.
Given the vulnerability of WinXP post support-end, AND the supremely careless browsing habits of my friend, I suspect there is still a chance of the virus being the root cause. He's getting a new Win7 PC now

Comment: Possible yes. Likely I have no idea. The BIOS is still booted before the LiveCD

Comment: Its unlikely a BIOS virus.  Those are extremely rare.  If I were to hazard a guess its likely a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a broken keyboard. Is there an email shortcut key? Other keyboard malfunctions would account for the other issues.

That or a novelty random keypress generator? Very unlikely to be a BIOS virus. Too hard to create to waste on stupid stuff like this.

Comment: I did suspect a jammed key (Multimedia keyboards can have Email keys I guess), but what was unique: I could type in all the credentials for Network connections in Ubuntu LiveCD alright, then it disappeared after 15-20 seconds.

The novelty keypress generator sounds more probable. On opening a DOS window in Safe Mode (WinXP), I could not run any command, but saw random strings being entered one after another...

Comment: Is the keyboard wireless? Looks like there is some history of strange behavior on wireless keyboards http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboard-Software/Random-characters-inserted-in-text-when-wireless-keyboard-is-in/td-p/147600. Keyboards can fail in very strange ways.

Comment: A close catch, but unfortunately no, its a PS3 keyboard :) This friend is actually my landlord, he's a senior. He was using a ball mouse till last week!
He did send his CPU to the mechanic (w/o the keyboard) and they found lots of virus on his PC (they could not clean it, the only option left is to format the drive/reinstall windows XP for h/w constraint).
I do not know if they at least found a BIOS virus to confirm my suspicion, but not a keyboard issue alone for sure.